# How to pass data from one form to multiple forms VB.net

Tags: vb.net, forms, winforms, visual-studio

My Form1 looks like this to get the value of textbox to pass the data to multiple forms.:

```
Public Class Form1

Public username As String

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    username = TextBox1.Text
    Form2.Show()
    Me.Close()
End Sub
End Class
```

At the second form, I used this code to show the data of username which was entered from the Form1.:

```
Public Class Form2

Private Sub Form2_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Label1.Text = "Hi " & Form1.username & "!"
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Form3.Show()
    Me.Close()
End Sub
End Class
```

It worked perfectly. The data showed up in the second form. But in Form3, it only shows "Form1"

Form3 code:

```
Public Class Form3

Private Sub Form3_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Label2.Text = Form1.username
End Sub
```

What should I do to make the data of username to show up on mutiple forms?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not use default instances of forms, create constructors for forms which takes username as parameter and then create forms explicitly

```
Public Class Form3
    Private _username As String
    Public Sub New(username As String)
        _username = username
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form3_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Label2.Text = _username
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class Form2
    Private _username As String
    Public Sub New(username As String)
        _username = username
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form2_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Label1.Text = $"Hi {_username}!"
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim formThree As new Form3(_username)
        formThree.Show()
        Me.Close()
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class Form1
    Private _username As String

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim formThree As new Form3(TextBox1.Text)
        formThree.Show()
        Me.Close()
    End Sub
End Class
```

With this approach you don't need to expose username as public property for Form1.